# How am I supposed to edit i3xrocks in regolith

Tags: i3, regolith

I am running the stable release of regolith-desktop 2.30-1ubuntu1~ppa1 and according to the [documentation](https://regolith-linux.org/configuring.html#config-files) **i3xrocks is customized** directly **in i3config**. Since i3xrocks’ config (which is the same as for [i3blocks](http://vivien.github.io/i3blocks/)) uses an INI file format and i3config does not—**how am I supposed to do this?** Customizing the config in `/etc/regolith/i3xrocks/config` is working though but obvoiusly this is not the way intendet by the author.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not supposed to edit the config *inside i3config* but to configure the *path to i3xrocks config file*

```
set $i3xrocks_config ~/.config/regolith/i3xrocks.config
```

you may first copy the original to the path of your choice, for instance

```
cp /etc/regolith/i3xrocks/config ~/.config/regolith/i3xrocks.config
```

When using the customized file for the first time you have to restart i3. After that a config reload via <super>-c should be sufficient to apply any modifications. You also can reload i3 via <meta>-r.